# Private directory gets unmounted on every login

Tags: release-loki, boot, system, sharing

Sup people!

Since a few weeks now, I noticed that, every time I log into my eOS machine via ssh, my private directory (~) is unmounted. Meaning there is nothing but two files, namely `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` and `README.txt`, in my home.

To access my files like normal, I have to follow the instructions given in the readme, which is basically just executing `ecryptfs-mount-private`. Funny thing though, when prompted to enter my "login keyphrase," I have to enter the password I had originally set for my account when I first installed eOS. When trying it with my current password, I just get asked to retry.

Why could that be? I honestly have no idea! Apart from installing some GUI apps and auto-mounting my Synology's network share on boot, I didn't mess with the system in any way. [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) is the tutorial I followed for mounting the network drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually could fix it myself. It had to do with the "Encrypt my home folder" option that I had ticked when installing the system. I don't know why exactly this behaviour was happening, but I could get around it by disabling the encryption of my `/home/`. Followed [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/) tutorial to do so.